# Can't display image in G sheets cell using Vlookup to get the link (returns blank or error)

Tags: image, google-sheets, vlookup

I have a Google sheet with answers to a form, and I created a template in Google Sheets to transform each row in the answers sheet in a report, using vlookup (=PROCV in portuguese). The last column in the  spreadsheet is a link for an image, uploaded by who answered the form.

The vlookup is working fine, except for the image. It's not displaying the image in the cell.

I have tried:

```
=image(PROCV(H7;'Respostas ao formulário 1'!1:630;21))
```

It returns a blank cell.

and also

```
=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&INDEX(SPLIT(PROCV(H7;'Respostas ao formulário 1'!1:630;21),"="),1,2))
```

and

```
=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(PROCV(H7;'Respostas ao formulário 1'!1:630;21),"id\=(.+)"))
```

which I found here in stackoverflow, in another question about this issue, and return an "ERROR".

Also important, I've already changed permissions in the image (anyone with the link can access).

Any insights, please?
Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I offered below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={file_id}` does not work, try this format:

#### Link Format:

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={file_id}
```

Try this publicly available image:
`http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1YEpZitKgY6YT0TMDvOX4uqoxD5_aTuEv`

#### Raw link image formula;

```
=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1YEpZitKgY6YT0TMDvOX4uqoxD5_aTuEv")
```

#### Formula using regexextract to get file ID:

```
=Image("http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(H7,'Respostas ao formulário 1'!1:630,21),"id\=(.+)"))
```

#### Outputs:

- Vlookup output:
  `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1YEpZitKgY6YT0TMDvOX4uqoxD5_aTuEv`
- Regexextract output:
  `1YEpZitKgY6YT0TMDvOX4uqoxD5_aTuEv`
- Raw link image output:
  [image: output2]
- Image regexextract output:
  [image: output]

#### Note:

- If the image is still not showing, there is an issue with your link and it may not be available to anyone else. To confirm this issue, open the link in incognito mode. If it shows, it is publicly available. If not, then it isn't and the image will not show using `IMAGE` formula.
- Make sure the one you append to the link format is only the ID and nothing else.
- See [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SNU_pFgazqM1EcYwhyD9vk9YjD2UX-jpvEEc87I_wX4/edit?usp=sharing)

#### EDIT:

- It seems your lookup ID contains `#`, add a backslash before it by using the below formula

#### Formula:

```
=Image("http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(regexreplace(H7; "#"; "\#");'Respostas ao formulário 1'!1:630;21);"id\=(.+)"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just changed my link for the public link you provided, and the imaged was displayed as it should. But my images won't be displayed. I wonder why. A difference I just found is: your image is .jpg and my images are .png. Do you think it could he related to that?

Comment: I don't think that's the case.. Can you provide the link to your image? @Thai

Comment: Of course! Thank you... the link is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YE5wyebHyfKducluY4lo2gMleDHGZx-t
I've tested opening in anonimous tab and it was displayed.

Comment: It works. @Thai. https://imgur.com/a/CjwFIKv

Comment: Whaaaaaaat, how is that possible? Let me take a moment, I'll delete everything and start fresh to find the error.

Comment: make sure the link looked up does not include `/edit`

Comment: Use `=Image("http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(H7,'Respostas ao formulário 1'!1:630,21),"id\=(.+)/.*"))` if you have characters after your file id in the link.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, the key was to change commas to semi colons!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "is_sorted" parameter to false. From your first formula I gather you are looking up the value in H7 against the sheet 'Respostas ao formulário 1' rows 1 through 630 and you want the 23 column (W). Some areas that can give you problems is setting the sort to false, so it has to be an exact match, is the lookup value in the first column of the resource sheet?

Essentially with a format matching this you shouldn't have any issues:

Sheet named 'Respostas ao formulário 1'. Notice I have hidden columns B:V to consolidate the image and only show important information.

[image]

Finally the formula sheet:

We are looking up the value in cell F1 "Value1" against the second sheet and returning the image from the link.

[image]

Comment: OP is talking about drive images. I think this is not the solution the OP wants. his VLOOKUP is working as he stated. The image is not.

Comment: Kevin P. thank you very much for your answer, but it didn't work, I still get blak cell... I guess @Octavia Sima might be right, maybe it's related to the fact that the link is for an image in my google drive account (uploaded along with a form answer). It is a publicly shared image, so it should be displaying, but it is not...

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your question to be asking why you were getting a blank cell value and your uncertainty of your formula's being accurate. You cannot in fact import images from a google drive because they do not have a direct link. They are opened within the Google Drive web application. You will have to host your images or "reports" on a different platform.

Comment: As long as you have the file ID and the link is publicly available to anyone who have it, it should be possible. See the answer I just posted. @KevinP.